# why some foreign keys are not saved in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am developing a web application in CakePHP 2.5.1. i am facing problems in saving foreign keys in database and showing associated data in web pages. i have users, managers, customers, houses, addresses and emails tables.

their relationships are ,

- a manager can have many customers,
- a customer can have many houses,
- a manager can have many addresses, many emails,
- a customer can have many addresses, many emails,
- a house can have many addresses

my requirements are,

- manager is the users
- after registration, the manager will add multiple customers. against each customer, the manager will add multiple houses.
- each user/manager has a profile/index page where all its customers will be listed.
- each customer has a profile/index page where all its houses will be listed.

Now, i can save all the data. but in the database, foreign keys are not saved, thus creating problem in showing associated data. for example, when manager's registration is done, it saves manager_id in the addresses table; but customer_id and house_id remain NULL. when a customer is added for the manager, it saves customer_id in addresses table; but manager_id and house_id remain NULL. But, it should save manager_id, since a customer belongs to a manager. similarly, when a house is added for a customer, it saves house_id in addresses table; but manager_id and customer_id remain NULL. But, it should save manager_id and customer_id, since a house belongs to a customer, and that customer belongs to a manager.

in AppController, i defined the relations like following:

```
'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authenticate' => array('Form' => array(

       'contain'   => array(
           'Manager'  => array(
                'Address' , 'Email' , 'Customer' => array('House')))
```

in the userscontrollers, i used following methods:

```
 public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
                $components = array('Session'); 
                $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome!');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __(' Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }
```

in the CustomersControllers, i used following method:

```
public function AddCustomer() {

   if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Customer->create();
            if ($this->Customer->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
                $primaryKey =   $this->Customer->id; 
                $components = array('Session'); 
                $this->Session->setFlash('Customer DATA have been saved!');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' =>  ‘index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The Customer Data could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
     }
```

in the HousesControllers, i used following method:

```
  public function AddHouse() {

         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->House->create();

            $this->loadModel('House');

            $houseData = $this->data['House'];
            $houseData[‘house_id'] = $primaryKey;

            if ($this->House->saveAll($houseData)) {
                $components = array('Session'); 
                $this->Session->setFlash(‘House DATA have been saved!');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The House Data could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
     }
```

when add() is used in userscontroller, it saves users and managers data with foreign keys.i.e manager_id is saved in users table as foreign key. but similar functions addCustomer() and addHouse() are not saving the foreign keys. customers table should save manager_id as foreign key and houses table should save customer_id as foreign key. since their relations are like - manager hasMany customer hasMany house. why theses similar functions are behaving differently here ? Can anybody give me any hints, why foreign keys are not saved ?

Comment: You need to manually save foreign key because foreign key generates when parent table data save.You should manually save data in each table.

Comment: @Tony stark , how to do that ? because, when the users will use the application, they won't be able to insert data into tables manually.

Comment: Have you some common sense. manually means manual save data in table . load each model and pass data array to save.
Like this : 
$saveData = $this->data;
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User($saveData);
$userId = $this->User->id;

$managerData = any data;
$manager['user_id'] = $userId;//Foreign Key
$this->loadModel('Manager');
$this->Manager->save($manager);

Comment: ok, thank you. you are great.

Comment: that your greatness. hay @Tom can i put my answer in answer tab?So you can mark as answered so that will helping to me

Comment: sure. please mention the codes clearly in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first save data in your parent table like users table
Like this

```
$saveData = $this->data['User'];
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->save($saveData);
```

Now get its primary key like this:

```
$userId = $this->User->id;
```

Now to save data in other table which are depend on '$userId' means $userId is now foreign Key for these tables like address , user details, managers etc;
Now to save data in address table

```
$addressData = $this->data['Address'];
$addressData['user_id'] = $userId; // This be foreign Key for address table
$this->loadModel('Address');
$this->Address->save($addressData);
```

Like this you should save data in dependent tables 
This complete code should be in your controller function where you want to save data.

Comment: where should i write this codes ? this should be written in same function in controller ?

Comment: yes , This complete code should be in your controller function where you want to save data.

Comment: what does this line $saveData = 'User data'; mean ? i have to input the data from input form where users will fill up the form with their data like address, phone no etc. e.g. i use following function in my CustomersController: public function AddCustomer() {

         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
 $this->Customer->create();
 if ($this-> Customer->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
 $components = array('Session'); 

$this->Session->setFlash('Customer DATA have been saved!');return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); }}}

Comment: how to fit your idea about taking primary key here ? please help, i am new in CakePHP :)

Comment: public function AddCustomer() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $this->Customer->create(); 
   $this->Customer->save($this->request->data);
   $primaryKey = $this->Customer->id;
   
   $components = array('Session'); 
   $this->Session->setFlash('Customer DATA have been saved!');
   return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); 
  }
 }
 here primaryKey is $primaryKey . you can use this to save data in other tables

Comment: ok, i have another controller HouseController where i used similar function to save house data where house belongs to a customer. if i follow your logic, should the function be like this -    public function AddHouse() {if ($this->request->is('post')) { $this->House->create();$houseData = $this>data[‘House'];$houseData[‘customer_id'] =  $primaryKey; $this->loadModel(‘House');if($this>House>save($houseData) ) {$components = array('Session'); $this>Session->setFlash('House DATA have been saved!');return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
}

Comment: yes you are right i have mention some comments in your code public function AddHouse() {
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $this->House->create();
  $houseData = $this>data[‘House'] //form data , first you should print and analysis like this pr($this->data); 
  $houseData[‘customer_id'] = $primaryKey //customer_id that is stored in customer table; 
  $this->loadModel(‘House');
  if($this>House>save($houseData) ) {
   $components = array('Session'); $this>Session->setFlash('House DATA have been saved!');return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); 
  }
 }

Comment: still facing the same problem. foreign keys are not saved.

Comment: hi try to understand , first you save data in add function , then you save data in  AddCustomer function and assign primary key to $primaryKey variable, then you save data in AddHouse . now how can you get $primaryKey  in Addhouse function. even you have not pass $primaryKey  to addHouse function so this is not possible. you should write a session $this->Session->write('primaryKey',$primaryKey); when and use this.

Comment: when add() is used in userscontroller, it saves users and managers data with foreign keys.i.e manager_id is saved in users table as foreign key. but similar functions addCustomer() and addHouse() are not saving the foreign keys. customers table should save manager_id as foreign key and houses table should save customer_id as foreign key. since their relations are like - manager hasMany customer hasMany house. why theses similar functions are behaving differently here ?